# How to close reactstrap modal on pressing escape button from keyboard in "React.js"?

Tags: reactjs

```
<Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Modal title</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
           ABC
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>Do Something</Button>{' '}
            <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>Cancel</Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
```

1. How to close modal on pressing escape button on keyboard?

Comment: Which Framework are you using we need more info about your issue please elaborate?

Comment: I am using react.js  and modal in react strap https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/

Comment: Right !, so look at the **docs** the feature that you want has to be there. It looks like is the prop ````keyboard```` and is a ````boolean```` You have to add it to the component ````Modal````

Comment: Actually My modal gets closed when I click on the cancel button of modal which works perfectly fine, Now I wanted to close the modal when I press Esc button on the keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code don't need to change. I think you are missed in others.
try this code. it's the same as your code.

```js
const {
  Button,
  Modal,
  ModalHeader,
  ModalBody,
  ModalFooter
} = Reactstrap;

class Demo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modal: false
    };
  }

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      modal: !prevState.modal
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>Click here</Button>
          
        {/*from here*/}
        
        <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Modal title</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>ABC</ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>
              Do Something
            </Button>
            <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>
              Cancel
            </Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
          
        {/*to here*/}
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<link href="https://npmcdn.com/bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15/dist/react-with-addons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/reactstrap@2/dist/reactstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Hey I need to close modal when I press Esc button from keyboard thats it. On clciking cancel button it works but on pressing Esc button it dosent works? How to achieve it?

Comment: @ShraddhaAgarwal, could you post the whole code to the sandbox? I will review your code. btw, my modal close well when I press the Esc button from the keyboard.

Comment: Hey I tried to execute your above code properly and its working!!! Thanks a lot you saved my time.